# How to convert File type to Image?

Tags: java, image, file, awt

I've got this code:

```
File obraz = new File("C:\\Users\\ender\\Pictures\\logo.jpg");
```

I would like to convert it into an `Image` from `java.awt`. How should I do that?

Comment: You are aware that _awt_ is long past, in the applet era. Then came _swing_ and nowadays _javafx (openjfx)_ is heavily in use. Still ImageIO is a basis also usable for swing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
try {
    File obraz = new File("C:\\Users\\ender\\Pictures\\logo.jpg");
    Image image = ImageIO.read(obraz);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Using ImageIO helper class.

Comment: Thank you Marcin

Comment: `Image image` I would always use `BufferedImage image` instead. The `ImageIO` method returns one, and there are other handy methods it implements. Plus one though, for showing exception handling in a useful way (that is, to print the stack trace).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Image img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\ender\\Pictures\\logo.jpg"));
} 
catch (IOException e) {}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: What does ,,null" mean?

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {}` Minus one. Don't teach poor programming practices. We spend an inordinate amount of time here, getting programmers who ask questions to put the line back in the catch to print the stack trace when things go wrong. And yes, things **do** go wrong, and this code will go wrong as soon as the programmer creates a Jar file (if the image is supposed to be part of the application) or tries to run the code on a different computer.

Comment: **BTW** I just checked the tutorial you linked & was horrified to see that it does the same thing. Be better than the tutorial.